# is it possible to put print strings/floats from a for loop to another text files?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, text-files, addition

for city,number in b:

```
city = '{:^30}'.format(city)
number = '{:<5}'.format(number)
print(city, number)
```

I used this for loop, after I clicked run, it gave me:

```
AKRON              65.5574
ALTON              69.6722
```

that's what I want to put into a new text file plus adding [61-70], is there any functions I can use to put them into a new text file? 
Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "plus adding [61-70]"

Comment: yes...I need to add [61-70] at the head

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a text file using following code:

```
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for city,number in b:
    text_file.write('{:^30}{:<5}'.format(city, number))
text_file.close()
```

Comment: I got it ! Thank you very much